# integer constant long long int?

Tags: c++, c, types

```
long long int
```

It seems to be valid in C. but is this valid in c++?

Comment: Currently it's an extension for compilers that do support it.

Answer (score 5):

The data type `long long int` is valid only in the C99 and C++0x language standards, it is not valid in C90 or C++03.  Some compilers such as GCC permit it to be used in those earlier language versions as an extension—when compiling as C90.  GCC will give a warning on its usage if both the `-Wlong-long` and `-pedantic` options are specified.

Comment: With language extensions disabled, I can compile it even in VC++ 8.0. Doesn't it follow C++03?

Comment: "following standard XXX" doesn't mean that it is "compliant to standard XXX".

Answer (score 1):

It's in the C++0x standard. This answers your question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that like all other primitive types in C and C++, only the ranges for the values the primitives may contain are well-defined; the actual size of the primitive, in bits, is left up to the implementation. I have not had much experience using `long long int`, since I prefer using the types defined in the `stdint.h` header. If you need to be sure that the primitive is, for example, 64 bits long, you may want to consider using `uint64_t` or `int64_t` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not portable in C++. What is normally done in programs is to have a single .h file that defines all the numeric types you are going to need depending on compiler/hw. For example you may find code like

```
#if defined(__THISCOMPILER__)
typedef long long int64;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
typedef short int16;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
...
#elseif defined(__THATCOMPILER__)
typedef __int64 int64;
...
#endif
```

then in the rest of the code only types like `int64` are used instead of the specific compiler-dependent declarations to keep most of the source portable.

C99 defined standard names for types of a specific size (or of a minimum guaranteed size) but not every compiler out there is fully C99 compliant so this kind of typedef include is still quite common. Note also that currrent standard C++ doesn't include C99.